# How to save all cookies on a page to a txt file (and log the page URL)

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to be able to console.log the URL and save the cookies to a .txt file.

I have tried

```
let currURL = driver.getCurrentUrl();
console.log(currURL);
(It just does Promise { <pending> })
```

and I have also tried to log all the cookies but it did not work.

```
driver.findElement(webdriver.By.xpath(`//*[@id="SIZE"]/option[2]`)).click();
driver.findElement(webdriver.By.xpath(`//*[@id="trackpants-ink"]/div/div[3]/form[1]/input[3]`)).click();
setTimeout(function(){
    driver.findElement(webdriver.By.xpath(`//*[@id="js-wrap"]/header/div[2]/form/div/div/div[2]/input`)).click();
    let currURL = driver.getCurrentUrl();
    console.log(currURL);
}, 5000);
```

I have not gotten any error messages the program is just not working how I would like it too.

Comment: You have to resolve the promise. `driver.getCurrentUrl().then(url=> console.log(url)).catch(err=>console.log(err))`

Comment: How do I turn that into a variable? B/c I can't do ``` newUrl = driver.getCurrentUrl().then(url=> console.log(url)).catch(err=>console.log(err)); ``` or ``` newUrl = url; ``` thanks for the fast help :)